# User Friendly CSV to MSSQL import with column match

Tags: csv, import, ms-sql

Hi before I reinvent the wheel I'm trying find something to allow a user to take .csv files and graphically match the columns in the database table to the columns in the csv file.  I know this can be achieved using the mssql import/export wizard or SSIS however if the column don't match exactly you start getting into t-sql.  Anything ?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [Quick CSV Import](http://www.assembla.com/code/quick_csv_mapping_import/subversion/nodes) or [DevArt dbForge studio](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) .

Comment: These look great thanks, however, I think there both for MySQL not MSSSQL

Comment: DevArt dbForge exist also for MSSQL .

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can convert CSV to SQL (and others). The generated SQL contains "insert" statements for each line and a "create table" statement.

The app works offline - your data never leaves your machine.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).